# .htaccess file to do is redirect the main domain but not the (100+) subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Who can give me some advice related to .htaccess rewrite rules ?

I have now activated https (SSL certificate) on my domain, but I didn't buy a multi-domain certificate.
So, what I need the .htaccess file to do is redirect the main domain but not the (100+) subdomains, meaning:

```
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://subdomain.example.com -> http://www.example.com
```

As I have 100+ subdomains, it needs to be generic.

Now, I have this .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

But this redirects all to HTTPS and it doensn't exclude subdomain which now give security warnings.
So, I probably need to add a extra Condition to only include only root and www.

Who can give me some advice ?

Jo

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below conditions,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```